# How to map a string to list of characters

Tags: scala

Given a string "my_string", how do I convert this to a list of Strings: `List("m", "y", "_"...)` containing the component characters

Comment: `"my_string".toList.map(x => x.toString)`

Answer (score 6):

If you specifically need a `List[String]`, axel22's answer is good.  However, note that a string implicitly acts like a `Seq[Char]`, which already gives you access to the methods you would likely be using on a `List`.  For example, you can do the following:

```
"my_string".filter(_ != 'i') // Gives "my_strng"
```

In other words, you can usually treat a `String` like any other container without explicitly converting it to one first.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
"my_string".map(_.toString).toList
```

It first implicitly converts a string into a `StringOps`, which is a **sequence of characters**, i.e. `Seq[Char]`. This is then mapped to a sequence of **strings** (`Seq[String]`) by converting each character in the sequence into a string. Finally, `toList` converts it into a **list** of strings, i.e. `List[String]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another trick:

```
scala> "my_string" grouped 1
res0: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> .toList
res1: List[String] = List(m, y, _, s, t, r, i, n, g)
```